# doing lookup on jndi name on wrong port

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jndi

I'm using jboss 7.1 . when doing lookup on jndi name , I see that although the jndi is configure to port 6341 , sometimes the lookup succeed also if for some reason I'm doing it on port 6001. this possible ?

the jndi configration :

2015-08-02  17:13:56,916+0300 INFO  [infra.event.MessagingSessionFactory] (main) [-] Building initial context from properties: {java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory,
jboss.naming.client.security.callback.handler.class=.auth.callback.CalypsoClientCallbackHandler, jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false, jboss.naming.client.remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false,
jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_DISALLOWED_MECHANISMS=JBOSS-LOCAL-USER, jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_STARTTLS=false, java.naming.provider.url=remote://ntvr107777a9a:6341, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.ejb.client.naming,
jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT=false}

my initialContext :

2015-08-04 12:27:12,264+0300 INFO  [SYSTEM.FIX_LOG] (AWT-EventQueue-0) [-] BloombergRequestor:initialContext :{java.naming.provider.url=remote://ntvr107777a9a:6001, java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory}

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two servers started?

Comment: yes this is possible.